# How do I look into Django based Database for Emails or phone Validation from Angular Front End

Tags: django, angular

I am working on a project consist of Django and Angular Integration. I have created RestApi in Django and receiving Data in JSON format. I added Resgistration module in Angular in which **I want to add Validation for non repeating email and phone number which calls Django api and checks for the validation** <-- how to do this :/

## Django Model

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    DESIGNATION = (
       ('Admin', 'Admin'),
       ('PM', 'Project Manager'),
       ('TL', 'Team Leader'),
       ('Dev','Developer'),
       ('QA', 'Quality Analyst')
   )
    employeeid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone_no = models.BigIntegerField(unique=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=50,choices=DESIGNATION, default='Dev')
    dept_id = models.ForeignKey(Department, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
```

## Django URL from which Angular receive JSON response

```
url(r'^employee/list/$', views.employee_list),
url(r'^employee/details/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.employee_detail),
```

Answer (score 0):

I advise you [django-lifecycle](https://github.com/rsinger86/django-lifecycle) library. Use before_create hook for the validation